# How to dynamically adjust html table based on browser window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my site to display differently based on the size of the web browser.  Based on the questions/answers from other users, I got this to work with JavaScript `onload`. But I can't get it to work dynamically -- that is to say, in real-time, as users are adjusting the window. They have to refresh to get the format of the webpage to change.

Here is my current code:

```
<table class="index_table" border="0">
<tr>
    <!--BELOW IS JAVASCRIPT FOR ADJUSTING HTML BASED ON WINDOW SIZE -->
    <script>
    if (window.innerWidth > 900){
    document.write('<td rowspan="3" class="index_article"></td>');
    }
    </script>
    <!-- END OF JAVASCRIPT -->
    <td class="index_article_light">
        <h2 class="index_instructions_subheader">INSERT HEADER HERE</h2>
        <p class="index_instructions">INSERT PARAGRAPH HERE.</p>
        <p class="index_instructions">INSERT PARAGRAPH HERE. </p>
            <br />
            <form action="signup.html" style="vertical-align:top;">
                <table border="0"  style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="firstname" value="&nbsp;First name">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="lastname" value="&nbsp;Last name">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="email" value="&nbsp;Email">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div style="color:#979797;">Password:&nbsp;<br /><input type="password" name="password" class="password" value="Password"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:#979797;">Verify password:&nbsp;<input type="password" name="verify_passwords" class="password" value="Password"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <select>
                                 <option value="kent">INSERT LIST HERE</option>
                            </select>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="signup!" style="float:right;" id="result_submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<!--BELOW IS JAVASCRIPT FOR ADJUSTING HTML BASED ON WINDOW SIZE -->
    <script>
    if (window.innerWidth < 900){
    document.write('<tr><td class="index_article" style="height:200px;"></td></tr>');
    }
    </script>
    <!-- END OF JAVASCRIPT -->
```

---

Note: I know I shouldn't be used tables, I should be using `div`s. But that's another issue...  I started building this website before I knew that. I also know it's pretty sloppy. So just bear with me. I'm trying to just go with it until I have time to fix it up.

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){ ... });

Comment: Don't feel bad, tables and iframes are not dead yet! And won't be in a closer future.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez Not sure what future you're looking at - they'll be dead in most new work pretty soon.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use JavaScript to make responsive web design. Use CSS instead, with media querys. So you write your HTML:

```
<table class="index_table" border="0">
<tr>
    <!--This only will display on screen-width>900-->
    <td id="big_device_index" rowspan="3" class="index_article"></td>
    <td class="index_article_light">
        <h2 class="index_instructions_subheader">INSERT HEADER HERE</h2>
        <p class="index_instructions">INSERT PARAGRAPH HERE.</p>
        <p class="index_instructions">INSERT PARAGRAPH HERE. </p>
            <br />
            <form action="signup.html" style="vertical-align:top;">
                <table border="0"  style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:400px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="firstname" value="&nbsp;First name">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="lastname" value="&nbsp;Last name">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="text" name="search" class="email" value="&nbsp;Email">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div style="color:#979797;">Password:&nbsp;<br /><input type="password" name="password" class="password" value="Password"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="color:#979797;">Verify password:&nbsp;<input type="password" name="verify_passwords" class="password" value="Password"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <select>
                                 <option value="kent">INSERT LIST HERE</option>
                            </select>
                        </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="submit" value="signup!" style="float:right;" id="result_submit">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<!--This only will display on screen-width<900-->
<tr id="small_device_index"><td class="index_article" style="height:200px;"></td></tr>
```

Use the following CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 899px) {
    #big_device_index {
        display: none;
    }
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    #small_device_index {
        display: none;
    }
```

You can find out more about media queries [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)
    }

Comment: So I would appreciate, if you could officialy "accept" my answer ;)

Comment: Done! sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Didn't even know you could do that haha

Comment: @red_trumpet Can my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683712/adjust-table-size-to-fit-in-screen-resolution?noredirect=1#comment47505652_29683712 solved with `@media` queries

Answer (score 1):

Add this outside of `if (window.innerWidth > 900){.....`

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        if (window.innerWidth > 900){
                $('.index_article').remove();
                $('.index_table).find('tr:first').append('<td rowspan="3" class="index_article"></td>');
        }
}
```

hope this will help you, make sure to include fisrt jquery.min.js