# Adjust table size to fit in Screen Resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have html page as below

```
<style>
    h2.message{text-align: center; color: #FDFDFD; font-size: 1.1em; background: #708fc3; }  
    #invoiceList{ float: left; width: 15% }
    #invoiceFrame{float: right; width: 83.5%;   margin-bottom: 0em !important; }
        td error { color: red; font-size: 100%;} 
       tr.errortrue { color: #c33; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;} 
        table#lines th { background-color : grey;  color: white; width:100%}
       table {margin-bottom: 2em; border-bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb; empty-cells: show; border-collapse: collapse; }
       table#lines td { text-align: center; width:100%}

    iframe { float: left; width: 100%;  height =300px;
        }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body id='foo'>
<div class="ui-widget">
<center><h1> Invoice Error Details For ePacket P00000079247</h1></center>
  <div class="panel ui-widget-content" id="invoiceList">
 <h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; font-size: 1.1em; "><span>Invoices</span></h2>
<table cellspacing='0' id='header' class="ui-widget">
                   <tr>
                        <th>Invoice Number</th>
                         <th>Invoice Total</th>
                  </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvPatentMatter</td>
              <td>1507.93</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvAppMatter</td>
              <td>1444.14</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvPatentOfProdMat</td>
              <td>1775.45</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvTrademarkMat</td>
              <td>1987.01</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvAcqMatter</td>
              <td>801.56</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvHenleyMatter</td>
              <td>567.89</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvCooperMatter</td>
              <td>760.53</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvACMEMatter</td>
              <td>439.01</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvFoxMatter</td>
              <td>337.67</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class = 'errortrue'>
                         <td>10InvMvAntiInvoice</td>
              <td>909.84</td>
            </tr>

        </table> 
</div>
<!-- <div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceDetails">
<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; "><span>Select the Invoice Number on the left to view the error details</span></h2>-->
<h2 class='message'><span>Select the Invoice Number on the left to view the error details</span></h2>
<div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceFrame"><iframe src="" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" scrolling="no"  class='panel ui-widget-content' onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
```

When you select any invoice number from the `header` table its details gets displayed in an iframe

Here is iframe source for one of the invoices

```
  </script>
       <style>
       #invoice {padding: 0;}
       tbody td{ border-top: 2px solid #efefef; border-bottom: 0px !important ;}
       td.error { text-align: left; color: #c33; font-size: 100%; background-image: none !important; padding-left : 0; border-bottom: 2px solid #0891F4} 
       tr.errortrue { color: #c33; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold;} 

       table {empty-cells: show; border-collapse: collapse; }
       table#lines td { text-align: left;}

       </style>
    </head>
<body id='invoice'>
 <div id="invoiceErrors">
  <div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceHeaders">
<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; font-family: Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em;"><span>Header Details</span></h2>
    <table class="ui-widget" id="headers">
                   <tr>
                        <th>Invoice Number</th>
                         <th>Matter Number</th>
                        <th>Invoice Total</th>
                        <th>Invoice Tax Total</th>
                        <th>Invoice Net Total</th>
                  </tr>

                     <tr class='errorfalse'>
                        <td>10InvPatentOfProdMat</td>
                         <td>6998</td>
                        <td>1775.45</td>
                        <td>1775.45</td>
                        <td>1775.45</td>
                  </tr>
<tr ><td class = 'error'  style="padding-bottom: 0%;">

</td></tr>
  </table> 
</div>
<div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceLines">
<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; font-family: Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em;"><span>Invoice Line Items</span></h2>

 <table class="ui-widget" id="lines">
<tr>
<th>Line Item Number</th>
<th>Line Item Date</th>
<th>Unit Cost</th>
<th>Number of Units</th>
<th>Line Item Total</th>
<th>Task Code</th>
<th>Expense Code</th>
<th>Timekeeper ID</th>
<th>Line Item Description</th>
</tr>

<tr class='errortrue'>
<td>1</td>
<td>20100510</td>
<td>1775.45</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1775.45</td>
<td></td>
<td>E109</td>
<td></td>
<td>E LI Patent of Prod Matter Invoice</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="9" class='error' style="padding-bottom: 12%;">

      Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for tax_type<br/>

      Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for inv_account_type<br/>

      Line : 1 inv_currency is a required field<br/>

      Line : 1 matter_name is a required field<br/>

</td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
 </div>
```

When the page is full screen it looks good as below

**Invoice Details With Good Resolution**   https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIVHn.jpg

But if the page is made smaller it gets messy, please check the images below

`div id = "invoiceList"`https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHdws.png

`table id = "header"`https://i.stack.imgur.com/71xm2.jpg

`table id = "header" tbody` https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFaGo.jpg

`div id = invoiceLines` https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nEql.jpg

`table id = "lines"` https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEkvH.jpg

`table id = "lines" tr` https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYqwU.jpg

I tried using `width:100%` for table as suggested in other posts but it didnt really work for me.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Is `table#header` position `absolute`, or it has a `float` property? You can also try  `#invoiceList{ float:left;width:15%;overflow-x:auto}`

Comment: `table#header` position is not `absolute` and it doesnt have `float` property

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, things like this are better made responsive by stacking them vertically.  Something like the grid and column system in Bootstrap helps nicely with this.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Using columns lets the elements stack nicely on top of each other instead of squishing them into little bits.